# Modularity Lifting Theorem by Lue Pan

Tags: reference-request, arithmetic-geometry

When I was searching for the proof of Modularity Lifting Theorem, I found [the paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.08565) by Luis Dieulefait. According to this paper it seems that there is recent Modularity Lifting Theorem proved by Lue Pan. However the source is not written and contents of the paper are written in Spanish and I can't read them. Where can I read about Modularity Lifting Theorem by Lue Pan?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.07166